# Use netcat as a proxy to log traffic

Tags: linux, bash, netcat, tee, named-pipe

I want to use netcat as a proxy to log http requests and responses to files, then tail these to inspect traffic. Think wireshark.

Tried the following where 'fifo' is a named pipe, 'in' and 'out' are files, netcat proxy on port 8080, server on port 8081.

while true; do cat fifo | nc -l -p 8080 | tee -a in | nc localhost 8081 | tee -a out 1>fifo; done

Problems:

- Netcat stop responing after first request (while loop ignored?).
- Netcat fails with msg `localhost [127.0.0.1] 8081 (tproxy) : Connection refused` if server unavailable on 8081. Question: Is it possible to "lazily" connect to 8081 when request is made? I.e. I do not want to have 8081 running when netcat is started.

Answer (score 11):

[ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat) can do this quite easily, using the --sh-exec argument.

The following command will allow you to see both directions of a TCP connection live, and allows multiple connections. The connection to `example.com` is done once for each connection received on `localhost:8080`.

```
ncat -lkv localhost 8080 -c 'tee /dev/stderr | ncat -v example.com 80 | tee /dev/stderr'
```

Change the two `tee` commands to `tee -a ./file` if you wish to log to a file instead of displaying it live.
You can also remove the `-v` to disable verbose output, leaving just the transfered data printed to the terminal.

```
-k, --keep-open            Accept multiple connections in listen mode
-l, --listen               Bind and listen for incoming connections
-v, --verbose              Set verbosity level (can be used several times)
-c, --sh-exec <command>    Executes the given command via /bin/sh
```

See `ncat --help` or `man ncat` for more details.

Comment: And this outputs http headers in proxied connections:
    'ncat -lvvv --proxy-type http localhost 8888'

Answer (score 5):

Use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/), you don't need the pipes and fifos

Comment: Works good. Im able to see the response now. But how do I make socat stay alive for subsequent requests? Tried `while true; do socat -v tcp-listen:8080,keepalive=1 tcp:localhost:8081; done` and `socat -v tcp-listen:8080,keepalive=1 tcp:localhost:8081
`

Comment: Try [`fork`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#OPTION_FORK) as in `socat -v tcp-listen:8080,fork tcp:localhost:8081`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) ([tutorial](http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/)) for this. I think the command you want would look like this:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -v port 8080
```

Comment: tcpdump only show raw packets which are hard to read.

tcpflow does exactly what I want and eliminate the need to proxy request/response.

`sudo tcpflow -p -i lo -c port 8081`